# Show $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx=2\pi \log 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, inequality

I want to show $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx=2\pi \log 2.$$

If I am allowed to change $\int$ and $\lim$, I can show this easily, but I want to show without changing $\int$ and $\lim.$

---

Let $t > 0.$

\begin{align*}
&\left|\int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx-2\pi \log 2 \right|\\
&=\left|\int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} - \log 2 \ \ dx\right| \\
&=\left|\int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x}{e^{2t}} \ \ dx\right| \\
&\leqq \int_0^{2\pi} \left| \log \dfrac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x}{e^{2t}} \right| \ dx \\
\end{align*}

---

So, I  want to find $g(t)$ s.t.
$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \left| \log \dfrac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x}{e^{2t}} \right| \ dx \leqq \int_0^{2\pi} g(t) \ dx \underset{t\to \infty}\to 0$. ($g(t)$ can include $x$.)

In order to find such $g$, I have to evaluate $\left| \log \dfrac{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x}{e^{2t}} \right|.$

So far, I don't come up with the evaluation and I searched the evaluation for $|\log u|$, but I couldn't find. (The famous inequalities $[\log x \leqq x$ for $x>0$], [$\log(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$] don't work.)

Is there  the idea of this evaluation ? or do you have another idea for showing $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx=2\pi \log 2$ without changing $\int$ and $\lim$ ?

Comment: For $u\ge0$ you have $\log(1+u)\le u$. Won't that be good enough? I mean the idea in the first approach is that for large $t$ both $e^{-2t}$ and $-2\sin x$ are just decorational items in comparison, quickly becoming negligible. So the estimate should reflect that.

Comment: Oh, I see that you may be worried about the possibility of negative $u$. Ok, then use the mean value theorem telling that
$$\left|\log(1+u)\right|\le2|u|$$
whenever $|u|<1/2$. Anyway $\log(1+x)\approx x$ when $x$ is close to zero. Using a constant multiplier gives you a definite upper bound, and won't disturb at all when you take the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the integral and then squeeze as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx
& = & \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\log 2 + \log \left(1+e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t}\sin x\right)\right) dx \\
& = & 2\pi\log 2 + \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} \log \left(1+e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t}\sin x\right) dx }_{I(t):=}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, you can squeeze $I(t)$. For $t> 0$ we have

$$-1 < e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t} \leq e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t}\sin x \leq e^{-4t} + 2e^{-2t}$$

Hence,

$$2\pi \underbrace{\log \left(1+ e^{-4t} - 2e^{-2t}\right)}_{\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0} \leq I(t) \leq 2\pi\underbrace{\log \left(1+ e^{-4t} + 2e^{-2t}\right)}_{\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0} $$

It follows that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^{2\pi} \log \dfrac{2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t}-2\sin x)}{e^{2t}} dx = 2\pi \log 2$$